# IPython does not allow editing r when invoked as `ipython console`

Tags: python, ide, ipython

When invoked as `ipython`, Its possible to do `edit myfile.py` which opens default editor with the file. I want to use the 'two process' model so that I can attach multiple clients to same kernel. But this doesn't seem to allow opening an editor. Is it by design? Is there a workaround?

```
hostname:folder$ ipython console
Python 2.7.3 (default, Oct 10 2012, 08:04:12)
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

IPython 0.13.2 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.
?         -> Introduction and overview of IPython's features.
%quickref -> Quick reference.
help      -> Python's own help system.
object?   -> Details about 'object', use 'object??' for extra details.
[IPKernelApp] To connect another client to this kernel, use:
[IPKernelApp] --existing kernel-56549.json

In [1]: edit somefile.py

In [2]:
```

Comment: The way %edit works in the two process model is a bit complex (because the frontend needn't be on the same machine as the kernel). So far, only the Qt console has the machinery to use `%edit`, and you'll need to set an editor in `ipython_qtconsole_config.py` before using it.

Comment: I wish I got a NotImplemented Error. Is there a bug report for this?

Comment: Yep: https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/3030

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From comments by @Thomas K
This is a known issue
https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/3030

`%edit` feature does not work in two process model.